# How do you shuffle a dictionary with list of strings as values such that no key is adjacent?

Tags: python, random, shuffle, password-generator

```py
# Create a function to generate a random, 8-character password.
# It should satisfy the following requirements:

# 1) There should be exactly two characters from each of the following categories:
# - Uppercase letters
# - Lowercase letters
# - Numerals 0 - 9
# - Special Characters from the string “!@#$%^&*”

# 2) No two character categories should be adjacent.
# bad example: AXyu74$^

# 3) The categories should be randomly ordered.
# good example: 8b&U6Nz!  NLSUNULS
# */
import random, string
def generate_password():
    store = {}
    for category in 'ULSN':
        store[category] = []
    for i in range(2):
        store['U'].append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters).upper())
        store['L'].append(random.choice(string.ascii_letters).lower())
        store['N'].append(str(random.randint(0,9)))
        store['S'].append("!@#$%^&*"[random.randrange(0,7) + 1])
    print("".join([item for sublist in store.values() for item in sublist]))
    for item in store.items():
        print(item)
     # shuffle and eliminate adjacency
generate_password()
```

There is a dictionary with four keys. Each key maps to a different category, and each key has a list of 2 characters as the value.

How do you shuffle the dictionary to build a string in random order, such that no key is adjacent?

The goal is to efficiently return a 8 character long string with no adjacent values.

Examples and test cases are in the problem statement

Comment: From `random` you can use `shuffle` to randomly reorder a list in place. For example, `L=list('LLNNSSUU')` followed by `random.shuffle(L)` will result in a shuffled list. You just need to write a function to verify that no key is adjacent. If there are adjacent keys, then shuffle the list again. The odds of getting a good list are about 34%. So the odds of  failing 100 times are less than `1e-18`, and on average only 3 shuffles are needed to find a valid permutation.

Comment: You can start with any of ULNS.  After that you can only pick from a subset of three, omitting the previous pick.  Just keep track of what category the previous character was so you know the three to pick.  Perhaps four methods: `notU()`, `notL()`, notN()` and `notS()` to return an appropriate random character.

Comment: @rossum Two problems. 1) You need **exactly** two characters from each category. So it's more complicated than just avoiding the last category. 2) Consider the sequence `ULNULNS`. Oops, the only category left to choose from is `S`, but you need `notS()`.

Comment: So keep track of what options are left from UULLNNSS.  Abort early if the last two options are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my answer

```
import string
import random

categories = "ULNS"
prev = curr = None
passwd = ""
used = {}
for category in categories:
    used[category] = 0

while len(passwd) != 8: 
    while prev == curr:
        curr = random.choice(categories)

    if curr == "U":
        passwd += random.choice(list(string.ascii_uppercase))
    if curr == "L":
        passwd += random.choice(list(string.ascii_lowercase))
    if curr == "N":
        passwd += random.choice([str(i) for i in range(10)])
    if curr == "S":
        passwd += random.choice([s for s in "!@#$%^&*"])
    
    used[curr] += 1
    if used[curr] == 2: 
        used.pop(curr)
        categories = "".join(list(used.keys()))
    prev = curr
        
print(passwd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Having slept on the problem, I think a solution is to break it down into two parts: a pattern and a mapping.

Every valid pattern starts with two different categories; call them A and B for the moment.  This gives AB****** as a starting part-pattern.  At some point a third category, C, will be used:

```
ABC*****
ABAC****
ABABC***
```

By completing these part-patterns you can generate a list of all valid patterns from ABCDABCD to ABABCDCD.  These patterns can either be hard coded into the program or loaded from an auxiliary text file.  By my rough calculation there are less than 6! = 720 valid patterns, though I'm not sure how many less.

Having picked a random pattern, you need a mapping from ABCD to ULNS.  A random shuffle of ULNS should be enough.  Read through the chosen pattern and use the mapping to determine which categories to pick from and in what order.

For example, pattern ABCADCBD with mapping LSUN gives LSULNUSN.  Breaking the problem into separate parts, pattern and mapping, makes it easier to deal with.